# Visual Studio: Setting a conditional breakpoint without setting an unconditional one first

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Sometimes, while I'm watching my program run, I'll want to set a breakpoint with conditions. At the moment, I'm doing this by clicking to create an unconditional breakpoint, then right-clicking to change the condition. This has the drawback that I'll stop the program on an undesired iteration. Is there a way to set the condition immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to suggest the macro route too. I got bored and had a go at it, if this macro runs it pops up a dialog and asks for the condition. You may need to make it a little fancier if you want more bells and whistles.

```
Sub addBreakpointWithCondition()
    Dim cond As String = InputBox("Enter the condition")
    DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add(File:=DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName,
        Line:=DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.CurrentLine, Condition:=cond)
End Sub
```

Comment: What's this DTE thing you mention? Will it persist over different solutions?

Comment: You can find more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.macros.dte.aspx . It's the root for all the automation variables (so in this case it's being used to find the currently selected file and get the line the cursor is on to provide to the debugger interface). So yes, this is all solution independant.

Answer (score 1):

Not through the IDE.  You could write a macro to achieve this, EnvDTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add() method.  It lets you specify the Condition property directly.  Not so sure that the time you'll burn on this is equivalent to pressing F5 repeatedly.